# Linked List Insertion & Selection

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I define a linked list in the same way as it is commonly used, i.e. with a **data** part and a

self referencing pointer. My logic of insertion is as follows:

```
struct node
{
    int data; //or any type.
    struct node *nextPtr;
}*start = NULL;
//main
struct *newPtr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
scanf("%d", newPtr->data); //or cout
newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
if(start == NULL)
    start = newPtr;
else
{
    while(tempPtr->nextPtr != NULL)
    {
        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    tempPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
}
```

i) Is this logic correct?

ii) a) I possibly get a **run-time** error, when I insert two nodes (in one system) or three nodes(in another).
b) The nodes are inserted in the correct order, every time I insert a node.

Is the **run-time** error as a result of this code...???

Comment: How is tempPtr initialized (and why is it not a local variable)?

Comment: if it isn't homework you would use std::list and not write your own.

Comment: Is `Read` a `typedef` of something? Otherwise the `->` should not work, but you also don't allocate...

Comment: Now why scanf? That is dangerous even in C when reading a string. Is this C++ or C?

Comment: Looks more like C than C++, given the manual assignment of `newPtr->nextPtr = NULL`. That should be handled by the constructor.

Comment: Examples should be as small as possible, but also complete enough to know what is going on. Hence all the comments here trying to figure out things you have left out of your example.

Comment: @wildplasser: Poor stuff. Have been using %d and %s. Data type doesn't matter, as Ithe nodes get inserted before the run time error. Do check my declaration where data can be of any type, and my point that there is no problem with insertion. I do get the nodes in the order U desire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct node
{
    int data; //or any type.
    struct node *nextPtr;
}*start = NULL;
//main
struct *newPtr = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));// You dont need * here

scanf("%d", newPtr->data); //or cout
newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

if(start == NULL)
    start = newPtr;
else
{ 
    tempPtr = start; // you missed this.
    while(tempPtr->nextPtr != NULL)
    {
        tempPtr = tempPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    tempPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I have that in the code I have here. Forgot to type. Sorry again.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct node *newPtr, **hnd;

newPtr = malloc(sizeof *newPtr);
if (!newPtr) barf();

scanf("%d", &newPtr->data);
newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

for(hnd = &start; *hnd; hnd = &(*hnd)->next) {;}

*hnd = newPtr;
```

Comment: This is missing the actual allocation of the memory for the new node in the list.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I just replaced the **while** part and the **hnd** declaration with what was given. So, memory allocation might have been allocated via the code, that I previously wrote.

Comment: Definitely not a homework. There are numerous programs available on the net. I could have simply used one. Why come here?

Answer (score 2):

**disregard the answer as it is c++, the original question was tagged c++**

The original code, once the small issues are solved (actual allocation of the node, setting the value, definition of the temporary pointer to help walk the list) should work. But there are other approaches that you can take to simplify the code (well, not that it is hugely complex), which basically imply finding the point of insertion before creation first then creating the new element:

```
Node** insertPoint = &start;
while (*insertionPoint) 
   insertionPoint = &((*insertionPoint)->next);
*insertionPoint = new Node(value);
```

Use a pointer to pointer to walk through the list, initialized with the address of the head pointer move it until it refers to the `Node*` where the new element will be appended (note, appended, not inserted). Then create the new node in that position. This assumes that the `Node` constructor takes care of copying the value and initializing the `next` pointer.

Alternatively you can write this recursively and let the compiler perform the tail optimization for you (it might be a bit simpler to read, some people find recursion simpler, some don't):

```
void append( Node*& tail, Value value ) {
   if ( tail==NULL )
      list = new Node(value);
   else
      append( list->next, value );
}
```

Calling code:

```
append( start, 100 ); // assuming nits contained in the list
```

In this case, instead of a double pointer we can use a reference to the pointer, as we don't need to modify it

Comment: The original question was tagged both C and C++, IIRC.

Comment: The same thing. A run time erorr after 2 or 3 inserts.

Comment: @user980411 people help those that help themselves... You are still getting errors but fail to provide the definition of `tempPtr` or a small self contained problem for others to help. Sorry, but I cannot *guess* what your problem is.